# static html and vue with bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a php laravel web page. There are many static html pages, and there are few pages where should I use SPA. I don't want to do neither a server side rendering, nor everything in vue.

My question that [bootstrap-vue.js](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) lib is able to work in this environment?

e.g.: If on my html page there is no spa code, but I want to use the bootstrap stuff (e.g.: css classes or dropdown), I will be able to?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Vue, (and by extension Vue with bootstrap) is a framework that can be used to provide functionality and UI enhancement to a single html page.  That html page can be static html or dynamically generated via php, or whatever backend code you like.

It's true that you can build a SPA with Vue, but it doesn't have to be used that way.  It can be used just on selective pages of your website. In fact, the default install of Vue (vue.js) doesn't include routing. The Vue router (vue-router.js) has to be included as a separate package if you want to have a SPA with routes.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help and advises.